# How do i solve $\frac{dy}{dx}- \frac {dx}{dy}= \frac {x}{y}-\frac {y}{x}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came up with this question in my exam. But i didn't get it right. Can someone show me how to solve this differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}- \frac {dx}{dy}= \frac {x}{y}-\frac {y}{x}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{x}{y}-\frac{y}{x}$$

Let $a=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $b=\frac{x}{y}$. We are given that $$a-\frac{1}{a}=b-\frac{1}{b}$$
Rearranging gives $$(a-b)(1+\frac{1}{ab})=0$$
Which gives us $$a=b$$ or $$a=-\frac{1}{b}$$

Plugging $a,b$ back, we have $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$$ or $$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$$

If $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$, we have $y dy = x dx$, so integration gives $y^2=x^2+C$, or $y=\pm \sqrt{x^2+C}$.

If $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$, we have $-\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{dx}{x}$, so integration gives $-\ln y = \ln x+C$, or $xy=C$, so $y=\frac{C}{x}$.

Therefore, the solution set is $y=\pm \sqrt{x^2+C}$ and $y=\frac{C}{x}$.

Comment: (+1) It is better to ask your question in a comment or maybe another question posted by yourself! :)

Comment: Thank you H. R. for your advice :) Now, being a beginner in differential equations, I have a question about this solution. How do I know, (or, how do I find a counterexample), that there is not a solution such that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$ for some $(x,y)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x}$ for some $(x,y)$? Thanks!

Comment: The answer to this question of you is easy as you just found some solutions that may satisfy these special ODEs. However, as you are some talented person in math, you may want to generalize your question for an arbitrary ODE. How do we know that there is a solution to an ODE? and if it exists, is it unique? These two questions is the main concern of the **Theory of ODEs**. You can start reading a book in this context and see what interesting stuff you may see! :)

Comment: @GyuminRoh It is possible, but ${dy \over dx}$ must still have meaning, so you can only "jump" between $y_1(x)={C_1 \over x}$ and $y_2(x)=\sqrt{x^2+C_2}$ in point $x_0$ for which $y_1(x_0)=y_2(x_0)$ and $y_1'(x_0)=y_2'(x_0)$ (you will find that $C_2=0$; upon further reading, you will learn that $y=\pm x$ is a special solution called *envelope* - it touches some other solution in every point).

Comment: @Gyumin how in your second step you got two odes

Comment: I edited the solution. Hope everything is clear now :)

Comment: @Gyumin Roh yes thanks for solution